# Is there a way to get the Base URL from an Application-scoped bean in JSF?

Tags: jsf, servlets, jsf-2

In my JSF Facelets pages I know I can just use

```
#{request.requestURL}
```

To get the full URL to build exportable links and the like.  However I have an @ApplicationScoped bean where I need the base URL (i.e. "http://dnsname/app") for the purposes of reports and other data.   Is there a standard way to access the web-app container to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not until the first HTTP request is fired. The domain/host/base is namely configured completely independently from the web application (on the appserver and/or proxy server, if any). If it's not an option to lazily set it as an application wide variable during the 1st HTTP request in e.g. a [servlet request listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener.html) or a [servlet filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) or perhaps in a lazy loading getter of that application scoped bean, then you'd need to configure it externally on the web application via e.g. system property, VM argument, properties file, etc.

Comment: Actually I figured out a similar way.  In my ApplicationScoped bean simply waits until something that has access to a FaceletsContext.getCurrentInstance() != null calls it -- then it gets the request URL from there.